# AJAX doesn't receive JSON encoded data correctly from Perl

Tags: json, ajax, perl

The Perl result has been encoded into JSON correctly and the response header has been set to "application/json", AJAX config seems no problem. Or Did I missed sth?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use JSON::PP qw(encode_json);
use CGI qw(:standard);


chdir( cwd() . "/gallery" );

my $cdir = cwd();
my @win = split ( ' ', `ls $cdir` );

my $res = [ ''.scalar(@win) ]; 

foreach my $w ( @win )
{
    open ( my $fp, "<:utf8", "$cdir/$w/tag.txt" );
    while( <$fp> )
    {
        unless( m#^\s*$# )
        {
            chomp;
            push ( @$res, $_ );
        }
    }
    close ($fp);
}

my $resInJSON = encode_json($res);


print "Content-type: application/json\n\n";
print $resInJSON;
```

Output from terminal:

```
Content-type: application/json

["2","2015-1-2 cat","2015-1-4 dog and girl"]
```

And the Javascript code is:

```
function loadGallery()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
     type: 'GET',
     url: "/cgi-bin/count.cgi", 
     async: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result)
        {
            document.getElementById("test-output-1").innerHTML = result[0];   // output is 3
            document.getElementById("test-output-2").innerHTML = result[1];   // output is undefined
            document.getElementById("test-output-3").innerHTML = result[2];   // output is undefined
        }
    });
} loadGallery();
```

AJAX Receiving dataType has been JSON.

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` tell you?

Comment: @Matt Jacob doesn't show anything!?

Comment: "AJAX doesn't receive JSON encoded data correctly" — How are you determining this? What does it receive? What does the Network tab in the developer tools show for the request?

Comment: @Quentin, I asked the same question as you did until I realized he did provide the information in comments (that are mostly off the screen) in the JS snippet.

Comment: Also, FWIW, Perl has native functions for listing files in a directory (no need to shell out to `ls`).

Comment: @Matt Jacob I figured that out. The problem is that the url: "/cgi-bin/count.cgi" is a symbolic link to a real .cgi in another directory, but chdir( cwd() . "/gallery" ); points to /cgi-bin/gallery which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to slice up `result[0]` so `result[0][0]="2"`, `result[0][1]="2015-1-2 cat"` and `result[0][2]="2015-1-4 dog and girl"`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a runnable demonstration. When I make it runnable, it produces the expected result.

`zzz.html`:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="test-output-1"></div>
<div id="test-output-2"></div>
<div id="test-output-3"></div>

<script>
function loadGallery()
{
    $.ajax(
    {
     type: 'GET',
     url: "zzz.cgi",
     async: false,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result)
        {
            document.getElementById("test-output-1").innerHTML = result[0];
            document.getElementById("test-output-2").innerHTML = result[1];
            document.getElementById("test-output-3").innerHTML = result[2];
        }
    });
}

loadGallery();
</script>
```

`zzz.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Content-type: application/json\n\n";
print q{["2","2015-1-2 cat","2015-1-4 dog and girl"]};
```

Output:

```
2
2015-1-2 cat
2015-1-4 dog and girl
```

---

It looks like the script called by your JSON returned

```
[["2","2015-1-2 cat","2015-1-4 dog and girl"]]
```

instead

```
["2","2015-1-2 cat","2015-1-4 dog and girl"]
```

Maybe you're not calling the script you think you are calling? Or maybe you are getting a cached response from an earlier version of the script?